# Are nightly builds useful for a web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, build, nightly-build

I keep reading about how important nightly builds (and automated builds in general) are to the development process, and I would love to implement them on my projects.  The problem is, I develop MVC web applications.  I cannot imagine how I would be able to easily *run* an arbitrary build.  I would need to deploy it to a server including any dll, view page, and DB changes necessary, and possibly seed the DB with appropriate test data.  That does not sound automatic or even useful.

Is there a useful way to do nightly builds in a web application?  The best solution would be one where I can access the application at an address like  `nightlybuild.myapplication.com/buildnumber` and the server would figure out what DLL, view pages, and DB to use.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to be able to access each build number individually, but providing a test environment with the current development version might be very useful for the stakeholders of your product. I also use nightly builds to test external resources like web apis, crawlers and so on.

Comment: @SebastianStehle For testing purposes, I want to be able to target a build to test with.  Then I can verify if a bug exists in a build, when it appeared, etc.